# I get: Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'. when making Google maps App

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I followed the instructions in this link: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start to make a simple android app with Google Maps API but I always get this error below when I run the app on my phone:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: method ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536

Comment: You might want to extend MultiDexApplication in your application class or set it as app name in manifest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

clean and see still error is there if yes,

1.go to your `build.gradle` file.
add `multiDexEnabled true`

```
 defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

2.in your dependencies add `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`

```
dependencies {
 compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
}
```

3.inside your application tag in menifest add  `android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"`

```
<application
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    ....
```

4.use this override method on your launching activity

```
 @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
```

Comment: I don't think you need to override attachBaseContext in your launching activity. That part is already done by MultiDexApplication. According to the documentation you should only override attachBaseContext if you override the Application class:
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Answer (score 1):

Check whether you are depending on the whole Google Play Services instead of just depending on the maps component. From [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

> If the number of method references in your app exceeds the 65K limit, your app may fail to compile. You may be able to mitigate this problem when compiling your app by specifying only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses, instead of all of them. For information on how to do this, see Selectively compiling APIs into your executable.

For example (using the last Play Services version), change this in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
}
```

To this

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1'
}
```

If you add other Play Services modules you will need to add them to your `build.gradle` individually.