# Can't build app with google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I integrated Google Maps API into my app and now it takes much more time for first start (even if I don't launch maps) and moreover I can't `Build APK` with maps. I can simply run it on device but I can't build it in Android Studio.

Dependencies:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.8.0'
```

Here are errors:

```
Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

So, two questions: how to decrease time for first launch and how to build app?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40958192/i-get-errorexecution-failed-for-task-apptransformclasseswithdexfordebug-w/40958284#40958284

Comment: and here --> http://stackoverflow.com/a/40958251/5188159

Comment: Problem with multiple libraries,you are using library file and gradle link,make sure you are using required library.Also add multiDexEnabled true in defaultConfig.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   android {
                ...
                defaultConfig {
                    ...
                    multiDexEnabled true
                }
            }
```

Use this in your app build.gradle file it will work.

Comment: And one more thing do you want to use map service only ?

Comment: Thanks! Now yes, but I don't know about later. What else do I need to know?

Comment: Do not use complete play service dependency, if you need only map service than use the dependency of map only.

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

Don't include complete play services libs in gradle file, they consume about 34 k methods from 64k method limit provided for an apk. So there are two solutions.

1. Add only required libs from play services, i.e. If you want to use maps then add this in your gradle

> com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.1

2. Enable multidex support for your app. To do this do the following steps

   ```
   android {

   defaultConfig {
   minSdkVersion 21 
   targetSdkVersion 25
   multiDexEnabled true// add this line
   }
   }
   ```

   And add this as a dependency

> compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'