# Android - Transform Classes With Multidexlist For Debug - Instagram JSON Parser

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-multidex

I'm trying to compile and deploy my Android App, but i have got an `MultiDex` issue :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
> java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException (no error message)
```

I already tryed many fix but they doesn't works.

**What i already tryed :**

**1.** multiDexEnabled true

**2.** dexOptions

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    preDexLibraries = false
}
```

**3.** Turning off *Instant Run* in Android Studio settings

**4.** Reboot Android Studio and computer.

**5.** *Clear* and *Rebuild* project.

**6.** *File* > *Invalidate Caches / Restart*.

**7.** *compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'* [EDIT]

And finally reboot my life but nothing want to works..

What can be done to fix this problem ?

Here is my **Gradle file**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'realm-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '24.0.1'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.X.Y"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 90
        versionName "1.2.3"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/dependencies.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LGPL2.1'
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    maven { url 'https://dl.bintray.com/X/maven/' }
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    // Utils
    //ANR Helper & Memory Leaks helper
    //compile 'com.github.anrwatchdog:anrwatchdog:1.1.+'
    //compile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2'
    // HoneyWell sdk
    compile files('libs/honeywell.jar')
    // RealmAdapter
    compile 'io.realm:android-adapters:1.2.1'
    // Volley
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    // EventBus
    //    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    // Gson
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    // Jjp
    compile 'com.instagram:ig-json-parser-processor:0.0.6+'
    // Sticky List headers
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.7.0'
    // Parallax
    compile 'com.github.nirhart:parallaxscroll:1.0'
    // Facebook
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.6.0'
    // Zbar
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.9'
    // NumberProgressBar
    compile 'com.daimajia.numberprogressbar:library:1.2@aar'
    // AutoFitTextView
    compile 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.+'
    // RoundedImageView
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.0'
    // UpdateChecker
    compile 'com.github.rampo.updatechecker:library:2.1.8'
    // UniversalImageLoader
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
    // GifDrawable
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.+'
    // PieChart
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:+'
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    //AndroidSlidingUpPanel
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.3.0'
    // YPL
    compile 'com.X:Xandroidlibrary:1.4.0'
    compile project(':kdcreader')
}
```

**And here Gradle Console**

> Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug]
>
> Configuration on demand is an incubating feature. WARNING: WARNING:
>   Dependency org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5 is ignored for
>   debug as it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by
>   Android.
>            In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages WARNING: WARNING: Dependency
>   org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5 is ignored for debug as it
>   may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>            In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages WARNING: WARNING: Dependency
>   org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5 is ignored for release as
>   it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>            In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages WARNING: WARNING: Dependency
>   org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.3.5 is ignored for release as
>   it may be conflicting with the internal version provided by Android.
>            In case of problem, please repackage it with jarjar to change the class packages :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE :app:preDebugBuild
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:checkDebugManifest :app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72311Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72330Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2510Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2510Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2510Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2510Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2510Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV132510Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42510Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidAnswers136Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidBeta114Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlytics255Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareComCrashlyticsSdkAndroidCrashlyticsCore238Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComDaimajiaNumberprogressbarLibrary12Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComFacebookAndroidFacebookAndroidSdk460Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGetkeepsafeRelinkerRelinker122Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGithubNirhartParallaxscroll10Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComGithubRampoUpdatecheckerLibrary218Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComMakeramenRoundedimageview220Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComSothreeSlidinguppanelLibrary330Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareComXXnandroidlibrary140Library
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:prepareIoFabricSdkAndroidFabric1310Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareIoRealmAndroidAdapters121Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareIoRealmRealmAndroidLibrary211Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareMeDm7BarcodescannerCore19Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareMeDm7BarcodescannerZbar19Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareMeGrantlandAutofittextview021Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:preparePlDroidsonroidsGifAndroidGifDrawable1117Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareSeEmilsjolanderStickylistheaders270Library UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:prepareDebugDependencies :app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugShaders
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE :app:mergeDebugAssets
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:fabricGenerateResourcesDebug :app:generateDebugResValues
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:generateDebugResources :app:mergeDebugResources
>   :app:processDebugResources :app:generateDebugSources
>   :app:incrementalDebugJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugNdk
>   UP-TO-DATE :app:compileDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithRealmTransformerForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug UP-TO-DATE
>   :app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug FAILED
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForDebug'.
>
>   > java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException (no error message)
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>
> BUILD FAILED
>
> Total time: 5.277 secs

[EDIT] And more info about crash : http://pastebin.com/vG79DLuN

Thanks for your help !

Comment: lol why that kiss :P

Comment: @Charuka to get more help xD

Comment: First try to avoid that warnings by excluding -- >http://stackoverflow.com/a/30460255/5188159

Comment: did you change anything in your build gradle?

Comment: Yes, but just app package by 'X'

Comment: add this to your app gradle dependency and sync and see -- >compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.0'

Comment: oh oops, I already tryed this, i just forgot to add it in _Already did_ list

Comment: mm this is what i do for multidex issue http://stackoverflow.com/a/40958251/5188159  go through it and see that you missed something

Comment: yep i'll check that

Comment: @Charuka i tried it but nothing works again.. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Try to see if you can get a more descriptive error. http://stackoverflow.com/a/37266244/5188159

Comment: Here is more info on crash : http://pastebin.com/vG79DLuN

Comment: Which is your min sdk?

Comment: Min SDK is : 15

Comment: I am also getting the same error since yesterday even though I didn't change anything in my build.gradle recently. Tried almost everything but same error exists.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a same issue. In my app I am using guava-retrying library, which was fetching **google guava library version 21**. Guava version 21 requires JDK 1.8 without providing back porting support and this was causing this error in my case.

I was able to solve it by including the guava-retrying library so that it uses version 19.0 of guava library:

```
compile ("com.github.rholder:guava-retrying:2.0.0") {
    exclude group: 'com.google.guava', module: 'guava'
}
compile 'com.google.guava:guava:19.0'
```

Comment: After some inspections, there was a dependance that broke my project : `compile 'com.instagram:ig-json-parser-processor:0.0.6+'`