# this error comes when i run google map project

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/40958251/5188159

Comment: Possible duplicate of [com.android.build.transform.api.TransformException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32807587/com-android-build-transform-api-transformexception)

Comment: @Charuka Multidex is not the solution to every gradle problem.

Comment: @Raveesh please [edit] your question with your `build.gradle`

Comment: may be this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001051/appdexdebug-execexception-finished-with-non-zero-exit-value-2

Comment: you will have to enable multidex.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to set JAVA_HOME path again.
Try adding multiDexEnabled true to your app build.gradle file.

```
defaultConfig {
     multiDexEnabled true
}
```